# How to configure ConEmu to start with gitbash and on a specific directory

Tags: terminal, conemu

I just installed the ConEmu terminal, and I am having trouble configuring it to start with gitbash as my terminal instead of the windows CMD, and I would like it to start on ex: `/c/Users/Kalin/Drive`

I tried to randomly pass values to the settings since they are very hard to understand. I have no idea what `{Shell::cmd}` means in the "tasks" category (which I guess is the place to change the configs) but I have no idea. The whole thing looks like something from a commercial aircraft and I'm lost :)

Comment: Yes. I have. Thanks, but even the manual is confusing for beginners. I don't understand 90% of it. Is this something difficult to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the following step-by-step instructions:

1. Open the settings menu.
2. Go to Startup -> Tasks in the left pane
3. Click the + at the bottom of the list of "Predefined tasks (command groups)"
4. In the big textbox, enter:

   c:\path\to\gitbash.exe -new_console:d:/c/Users/Kalin/Drive
5. Save settings

The key thing to recognise is that this is the minimal config. To begin with, you will ignore all the options. When you want to do the next tweak, then look for it in the manual.

Comment: I  don't understand I did everything like you wrote and it doesn't work: `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe -new_console:d:/C/Users/Kalin/Drive` I also tried to make the gitbash first option as default ... nothing working it starts in the `C:\Program Files\Git\Bin` dir

Comment: I also tried with `Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe` instead of `Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe` I can't see how people manage to configure this honestly

Comment: Oh God it took way more time to configure than it should but at last it worked, you have to go General to select your config ... meh  the setting is brutal but thanks for poiting me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

In the [latest version](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/releases/tag/v21.04.22), this configuration is more simplified. Just do as follows

1. Go to {Bash:Git bash} predefined task
2. In the big text area, keep your cursor to the end of the prepopulated text, so that it is right after `-new_console:d:` text
3. Below the big text area, you will see the following options

> Add: Tab... | Startup dir... | File Path ... | Active tabs

4. Just pick your startup directory from `Startup dir...` option
5. Restart ConEmu and you will see the session starts with the startup directory you have configured.

Answer (score 0):

NameGoesHere's answer worked for me. I just had to make one modification on the fourth step:

When you set your directory you need to use "new_console:d:c/Users/Kalin/Drive", whithout the bar after "new_console:d:".

Answer (score 0):

Rather the simple way must be to add the path under `Task Parameters` as

> /dir "C:\Dir\subDir....."